# How do kubernetes services balance load internally?

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-service

I got the following architecture:

```
     [Service]
    /    |    \
 [Pod1][Pod2][Pod3]
```

We assert the following Pod IPs:

- Pod 1: 192.168.0.1
- Pod 2: 192.168.0.2
- Pod 3: 192.168.0.3

I am executing a loop like this:

```
for ((i=0;i<10000;i++)); do curl http://someUrlWhichRespondsWithPodIP >> curl.txt; done;
```

This writes the pods IP 10000 times. I expected it to be round robin schemed but it was not. File looks similar to this:

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.1
```

The service config looks like this:

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: service
  ports:
  - name: web
    protocol: TCP
    port: 31001
    nodePort: 31001
    targetPort: 8080
```

Anyone has an idea what kind of internal load balancing Kubernetes is using?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using the default `iptables` mode of kube-proxy, which uses iptables NAT in random mode to implement load balancing. Check out the `ipvs` support (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-ipvs) for a big pile of other modes including round robin.